# WPF Through mouse click image control on transparency window

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, transparency

I making a window with XAML

```
WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" option,
```

when `Opacity = 0` or Transparency Image is Through mouse click to Desktop Like this,

[image]

But I Want Through mouse click to Desktop even not Transparency Image.

[image]

I know ways to set `WindowLong GWL_EXSTYLE`, but I Want Through mouse click to Desktop Only that Giraffe image control

Comment: you should try rephrasing your problem. it's unclear to me and the 2 snapshots don't express the idea well here.

Comment: sry King King
I want pass-through mouse event to desktop in WPF Window,
i use AllowsTransparency option in XAML, so i can pass-through mouse event in Transparency Area,

but i want pass-through mouse event to desktop even some control(not transparency)
what should I do?

Comment: I think googling would give you some result. I believe you can achieve what you want but with a note that we can only make a WPF window transparent to mouse events when its `AllowsTransparency` is `true` and of course `WindowStyle` is `None`.